# Reg Ex for amount not equal to 0.00

Tags: regex

I need a reg ex expression to capture any amount that is not equal to 0.00

Values that should NOT match:

```
0.00
```

Values that should match:

```
0.01
2.00
563.34
4,667.00
6,000.00
etc...
```

Basically any value that does or does not contain a comma and is not equal to 0.00

This is as close as I can get but it doesn't work for everything:

```
^[^0]*\.\d*
```

Thanks

Comment: The thousand with the `,` as well?

Comment: did you want to match integer numbers?

Comment: The , may be there or may not.  Depends on the size of amount.  Yes this is a dollar amount field (but there is no dollar sign).

Comment: A regular expression is not the right tool for every job. In this case, it's far easier to write a regexp that matches numbers equal to `0.00` and test that a string *doesn't* match. What language are you using?

Comment: What about `0`, `.00`, `0.0` or `0.000` - should they be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
(?!^0\.00+$)^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gJ0hU7/2)

Comment: Better, but now it allows `0.000` - perhaps `(?!0\.0+$)` would be a better fit, depending on what values can be input. (And neither will reject `0` or `.00`)...

Comment: It's hard to understand the op needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^(?![0,.]*$)\d+(,\d{3})*\.\d{1,2}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pB3mC1/1)